# How to mock react navigation params value with jest

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I am new to jest and I am trying to test the rendering of a component, but I am having problems when mocking the params it receives thanks to react navigation.

This is the test:

```
describe('<GameScreen /> tests', () => {
it('Render the component correctly ', () => {

    const route = {
      isAccesibilityModeOn: false
    }
    const navigate = jest.fn();
    const tree = renderer.create(<GameScreen route= {route} navigation={{ navigate }} />).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

This is my component, which is receiving a boolean value in the form of the variable `isAccesibilityModeOn`:

```
export default function GameView({route, navigation}) {

  const {isAccesibilityModeOn} = route.params;'
  
 return(<Text>Hello</Text>)
}
```

The error the console gives me is this

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAccesibilityModeOn' of undefinedJest
```

So the question is, how can I mock the value of parameters of the component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at `route` object you pass as a prop - it's missing `params` property. In component you try to access `isAccesibilityModeOn` property of unknown `params` therefore you see this error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you tell me how to add the params property? I'm confused in exactly where to put it.

Comment: Replace your `route` definition with `const route = { params: { isAccesibilityModeOn: false } }`. It should work just fine then.